# Consequences of finite many twin primes?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, twin-primes

Suppose , it turns out that the number of twin primes is finite (this is very unlikely, but let us assume it).

> Which consequences would such a result have for number theory ?

To be more concrete : Which important conjectures in number theory rely on the infinitude of the twin-primes and would therefore be refuted ?

Comment: The only statement that I know (is an alternative formulation) is part 2 of **Theorem 2** from *Alternative Formulations of the Twin Prime Problem* by Maria Suzuki, The American Mathematical Monthly
Vol. 107, No. 1 (Jan., 2000), pp. 55-56. You can to read it as a  free article view (this is the way from which I can read it online) if you have a JSTOR account.

Comment: Not very important, but minimal Goldbach partitions would need to be greater than 8 apart.

Comment: oh, and infinitely many primes would be forced to be of forms $6ij+i+j,6ij+i-j,6ij-i-j$